# Unity C# The script class can't be abstract

Tags: c#, unity3d, классы, интерфейс

Столкнулся с проблемой, не дающей использовать скрипт на игроке. Прогуглив проблему, понял, что юнити буквально не понимает, что именно я хочу использовать : интерфейс или класс. К решению так и не пришел, не понимаю ничего в абстрактных классах и interface.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public interface IInteractable 
{
void Interact();
string GetDescription();
}



public class PlayerInteraction : MonoBehaviour {

public Camera mainCam;
public float interactionDistance = 2f;

public GameObject interactionUI;
public TextMeshProUGUI interactionText;

private void Update() {
    InteractionRay();
}
//...
```

Источник : [код](https://pastebin.com/P2Y5yTAt) и [видеоролик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVkosA9kFg0)

Comment: Кажется, что либо весь Ваш код находится в одном файле - IInteractable.cs, либо в вопросе Вы что-то не то написали и на самом деле один из ваших классов - абстрактный - и ошибка сигнализирует об этом.

Comment: Верно, находится в одном файле. Как мне исправить ошибку? разделить интерфейс и класс по разным файлам? Как тогда в класс получать значения?

Comment: любой класс, наследник MonoBehaviour или ScriptableObject, должны быть описаны в отдельных файлах, названных идентично именованию Класса. т.е. Вам следует отдельно создать файлы PlayerInteraction.cs и ColorChanger.cs

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь добавить к объекту не скрипт, а интерфейс, что не является реализацией.
Вместо того чтобы добавлять к объекту IInteractable.cs, создайте новый скрипт {Ваше название скрипта}.cs и унаследуйте его от IInteractable:

```
public class YourScript : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    public void Interact()
    {
       // Ваш код...
    }
    public string GetDescription() => "Ваше описание";
}
```

Далее просто перетащите файл {Ваше название скрипта}.cs в инспектор и получите резултьтат.